# How to set width or height of image inside listview follow 4 inch of screen?

Tags: wpf, win-universal-app

I just want to set width of height of image on device 4 inch. 
How to set it? I develop on universal app.

Note: **That is 4 inch.**

```
<grid layoutUpdated="Grid_LayoutUpdated">
    <listview>
        <listview.itemsTemplate>
              <datatemplate>
                  <grid>
                     <image source="a.png" width=100 height=100>
 ...........


 private void Gird_LayoutUpdated(.....)
    {
      what do I write?....
    }
public  static DependencyObject MyFindListBoxChildByName(DependencyObject parant, string ControlName)
    {
        int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parant);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var MyChild = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parant, i);
            if (MyChild is FrameworkElement && ((FrameworkElement)MyChild).Name == ControlName)
                return MyChild;

            var FindResult = MyFindListBoxChildByName(MyChild, ControlName);
            if (FindResult != null)
                return FindResult;
        }

        return null;
    }
```